# How to remove the new line with a v-if

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs3

I would like in the middle of a sentence to put a *v-if*.
However I do not want a new line created in the middle of this sentence.

Here what I want  :

A / B / C / D

Here what I have :

A / B

/ C

/ D

Here my code :

```
  <div>
            {{ A }} / {{ B }} <p v-if="function()"> / {{ C }} </p> / {{ D }}
  </div>
```

Do you have any solution ?

Comment: use `span` instead of `p` element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`<template v-if>`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Conditional-Groups-with-v-if-on-lt-template-gt) instead of an actual DOM node:

> [...] a `<template>` element, which serves as an invisible wrapper. The final rendered result will not include the `<template>` element.

```
<div>
    {{ A }} / {{ B }} <template v-if="function()"> / {{ C }} </template> / {{ D }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand this is just a style issue. a `<p>` tag is a block by default (`display: block`). Use a `<span>` tag instead:

```html
<div>
   {{ A }} / {{ B }} <span v-if="function()"> / {{ C }} </span> / {{ D }}
</div>
```

Or alternatively you can apply `display: inline` to it:

```css
p {
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: the alternative solution will make all paragraph tags inline, which is not something you want.

Comment: @IgorMoraru, The point is that it can be done with CSS, obviously this can be applied with the an unique id / class